# Setting TypeVar upper bound to class defined afterwards

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, type-annotation, typeshed

I was looking through the `typeshed` source and saw that in the `pathlib.pyi` it does the following:

```
_P = TypeVar('_P', bound=PurePath)

...

class PurePath(_PurePathBase): ...
```

I have a similar case with a base class that returns a subclass from `__new__` (similar to `Path`), so the type annotations would therefore be similar as well. However, defining the `bound` keyword to the class that is defined below it resolves to an *NameError* since the name has not yet been resolved (as I would've expected; trying due to `typeshed` source).

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Type
from typing import TypeVar
from foo.interface import SomeInterface

_MT = TypeVar('_MT', bound=MyBaseClass)

class MyBaseClass(SomeInterface, ABC):
    def __new__(cls: Type[_MT], var: int = 0) -> _MT:
        if var == 1:
            return object.__new__(FirstSubClass)
        return object.__new__(cls)

class FirstSubClass(MyBaseClass): pass
```

How does `typeshed` get away with this? It would be perfect for my typing, otherwise I must do:

```
_MT = TypeVar('_MT', covariant=True, bound=SomeInterface)
```

And all my linter warnings are satisfied (`"expected type _MT, got object instead"`)...

Better matching case is the [typing a factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42226930/7811364) since I am using `__new__` as a factory similar to how `Path` does it and as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076300/7811364). Still, it would be nice to know how `typeshed` accomplishes this forward reference to `bound` without using a string.

Comment: I'm not sure how `typeshed` gets away with it, but what if you try `bound="MyBaseClass"`?

Answer (score 2):

In runtime Python code, you can use [string literal types](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) in the `bound` attribute to create a forward reference:

```
>>> _MT = TypeVar('_MT', bound='MyBaseClass')
>>> _MT.__bound__
ForwardRef('MyBaseClass')
```

As for why a non-string can be used in `typeshed`, it's because `typeshed` provides `.pyi` [stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files), which are syntactically valid Python code, but are not meant to be executed, only to be examined by type checkers. There's little I could find on specifications for stub files, but it makes sense to assume that everything is implicitly a string literal. This seems to be implied from the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runtime_troubles.html#string-literal-types):

> String literal types are never needed in `# type: comments` and stub files.